# Getting bounding box of axis and colorbar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I want to place my `legend` centered above the `axis` and `colorbar`, but I can't find the correct bounding box.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\pgfplotstableread{
x y z
5 5 1
6 6 2
7 7 3
8 8 4
}\mytable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={ytick={1,2,3,4},ylabel={z}},
    legend style={at={(current bounding box.north)},anchor={south}}
]

\addplot [scatter,scatter src=\thisrow{z},only marks,mark=*] table {\mytable};

\legend{loooooooooooooooooooooooooong entry}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\pgfplotstableread{
x y z
5 5 1
6 6 2
7 7 3
8 8 4
}\mytable

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}[local bounding box=plot]
\begin{axis}[legend to name=named,
    colorbar,
    colorbar style={ytick={1,2,3,4},ylabel={z}},
   % legend style={at={(current bounding box.north)},anchor={south}}
]

\addplot [scatter,scatter src=\thisrow{z},only marks,mark=*] table {\mytable};

\legend{loooooooooooooooooooooooooong entry}

\end{axis}
\end{scope}
\node[anchor=south] at (plot.north) {\ref{named}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Should be use with `\ref*{named}` if the `hyperref` package is loaded

Comment: @ben Yes, good point. (The MWE does not load hyperref. ;-)